# Spatial Index slows down query with STContains

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, spatial-index, spatial-query

I'm testing if I can use spatial indices on SQL Server 2012.

So, I've got a table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Records]
(
 [ID] [uniqueidentifier] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 [Value] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 [Padding] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 [Bounds] [geometry] NOT NULL
)
```

and an index

```
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [RecordsSpatialIndex]
ON [Records]([Bounds])
USING GEOMETRY_GRID
WITH
(
    BOUNDING_BOX = (0, 0, 2000, 2000) -- all coordinates are within this range
);
```

[Bounds] column contains 5-point polygons, actually rectangles (x1 y1, x1 y2, x2 y2, x2 y1, x1 y1).

@bounds variable contains the same type of rectangle. Strange thing is that the following query

```
SELECT
    [ID], [Value], [Padding]
FROM
    [Records]
WHERE
    ([Bounds].STContains(@Bounds) = 1)
```

runs more than three times faster without the spatial index.

With the index 65% of time is Clustered Index Seek over Records table and 29% is Filter. Totally 65 seconds.

Without the index 92% of time is Filter and 8% is Clustered Index Scan over Records table. Totally 19 seconds.

So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check out the query plan.   There are times when the query optimizer is not optimal.  But it collects statistics and get smarter.

Answer (score 2):

Also this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895265.aspx) was helpful to me in understand how to create indexes which are useful for particular queries